# Trying to loop setFormula() through open sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-sheets-macros

I'm using an add-on (toTabs) that separates a sheet of data based on the value in column H. It generates a new sheet for each unique value in H2:H, and then places a filter() in cell A2 on each sheet. This works wonderfully, except my next step is to export each sheet to .csv, and I need to get rid of H:H before doing that.

I'm trying to write a script that changes each filter from A2:H to A2:G and either ignores the rest of the formula, or replaces the text that the filter searches for to the sheet name, then loops through every sheet except for specific sheets. I feel like I'm 95% of the way there, but the loop isn't working quite right. Here's what I have so far:

```
function Loop() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();

  // Array holding the names of the sheets to exclude from the execution
  var exclude = ["Raw Input","Remove Chuff","Filtered Input","Final Input","Data Values","blank","totabs"];

  for(var s in allsheets){
    var sheet = allsheets[s];

    // Stop iteration execution if the condition is meet.
    if(exclude.indexOf(sheet.getName())==-1) continue;

  var cell = s.getRange("A2");
  cell.setFormula('=Filter(\'Data Values\'!A2:G,\'Data Values\'!H2:H="'+ SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName() + '")');
  s.getRange('H:H').activate();
  s.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  s.getRange('F:F').activate();
  s.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('00000');

  }
}
```

[Here's](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSByNc3mxNZ8DfwEXPEe97T5V_ErZeXxxQupxqzNoxWwnqkmX6wU2DrkkCYefE1_0XrHZN0e98clqEH/pubhtml) a copy of the file with all the irrelevant tabs hidden. Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Loop() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  var exclude = ["Raw Input","Remove Chuff","Filtered Input","Final Input","Data Values","blank","totabs"];
  for(var i=0;i<allsheets.length;i++){
    var sheet = allsheets[i];
    if(exclude.indexOf(sheet.getName())!=-1) continue;
    sheet.getRange("A2").setFormula('=Filter(\'Data Values\'!A2:G,\'Data Values\'!H2:H="'+ sheet.getName() + '")');
    sheet.getRange(1,8,sheet.getLastRow(),1).clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
    sheet.getRange(1,6,sheet.getLastRow(),1).setNumberFormat('00000');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The loop is working now, however it's no longer respecting the blacklist.

Comment: I just copied that line from yours and you had it wrong so I changed it and it should work now.

Comment: I appreciate it. Looks like there's one last bug (hopefully).  ss.getActiveSheet().getName() is grabbing the name of the sheet that's active at the time the script is started. Do you know how I can change that to grabbing the name of the sheet that is being modified?